# How to persist bearer token on client side

Tags: security, cookies, asp.net-web-api, access-token, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to get my head around claims based authentication in ASP.NET Web API 2. In my application I use the VS 2013 template, which implements OAuth 2.0 and uses bearer token (JWT as I remember). My question is - what is the best way to persist token on the client side. In his book Badrinarayanan Lakshmiraghavan describes bearer token as

> A bearer token is like cash: finders, keepers.

Therefore, is it safe to save it to a cookie? Doesn't it mean that whoever will steal the cookie will get full access to the application? On the other hand I could encrypt the token using hash just before saving it to the cookie. Would it be safe enough? Are there any other alternatives? I've seen few questions asking similar question on stackoverflow, but have never found satisfying answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it safe to save it to a cookie?

No. Cookies can be stolen via XSS attacks (and other vectors)
Also, this might be susceptible to CSRF since a cookie will be submitted automatically with any request.

> I could encrypt the token using hash just before saving it to the cookie

This will also not work. Hashing is *not* a secure way to encrypt (and moreover does not allow decryption)

> Are there any other alternatives?

Basically, you should give the token to the user over a secured connection (HTTPS) but they should manually submit it for security (again over HTTPS)

Comment: 'Basically, you should give the token to the user over a secured connection (HTTPS) but they should manually submit it for security (again over HTTPS)'. Still does not answer the question entirely. Does it mean that as long as I use HTTPS it is ok to use the cookie?

Comment: No. Cookies can be stolen easily via an XSS attack. Cookies are also automatically submitted with any web request so they are susceptible to Cross-Site Request Forgery. Check out (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) for more info.

Comment: The default timespan for bearer token in Web API 2 is 14 days. How do you preserve this token on the client side then?

Comment: Ah. If the bearer token expires after 14 days you're ok to store it in a cookie. The important thing is not to use cookies for *permanent* secrets. Just be sure to back your state-changing operations (if your users change settings, create/delete stuff, buy items) with randomized tokens for CSRF protection in addition to the bearer token.

Comment: @akirilov If cookie is HttpOnly it can not be stolen via an XSS. However WebStorage always can. Still, cookies are vulnerable to CSRF, but CSRF-tokens can deal with it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  How should the JWT token be persisted client side?